# SQL, корректное использование NOT LIKE

Tags: sql, like

Возможно, я не правильно понял документацию и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
SQL-запрос вида:

```
SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE `type` NOT LIKE '%error%' OR `type` NOT LIKE '%warning%'
```

Выполняется некорректно. 
Записи извлекаются корректно до условия OR, далее NOT LIKE игнорируется и извлекает записи, в которых находится слово warning.

Собственно,  вопрос: всё же, как корректнее будет использовать LIKE с предикатом NOT? 
И если условий запроса будет более двух, скажем, 3 или 4.

Comment: А если попробовать так: SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE (`type` NOT LIKE '%error%' OR `type` NOT LIKE '%warning%') ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предикат оценивается как истина, если выполнено хотя бы одно условие.
Используйте AND вместо OR.